# Использование MapFragment внутри ViewPager: Не загружается карта

Tags: android, google-maps-api, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Имею ViewPager, который подгружает MapFragment. При этом карта не видна, но фон меняется на серый, т.е. можно четко понять, что фрагмент MapFragment прикрепился без проблем, но по какаим-то причинам карта не видна на экране.

Как это исправить?

Мой **fragment_map.xml**

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Мой **MapFragment.java**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final String MAP_FRAGMENT_LOG_TAG = "map_fragment_log";

private MapView mMapView = null;
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap = null;

public static MapFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(MapFragment.this.getActivity().getBaseContext());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                    .title("Marker")
                    .draggable(true)
    );
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}

}
```

Мой **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="стерто" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="стерто" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="стерто" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: onMapReady вызывается?

Comment: @YuraIvanov Проверил. Вызывается.

Comment: А в logcat'е ничего? Возможно проблемы с ключом... Стоит попробовать перегенерить ключ. https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403

Comment: @YuraIvanov Большое спасибо за оперативную помощь. Проблема решилась. Использовал SHA1 релизного ключа, а ведь приложение подписывается дебажным, которого не было. Никогда бы не подумал в эту сторону. Еще раз большое спасибо.

Comment: @AlexanderLomovskiy, напишите как решили проблему в ответе - это может помочь будущим вопрошающим в аналогичной проблеме)

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с ключами. Они должны быть прописаны в двух файлах. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552467/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82-fragment-c-googlemap-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83/552606#552606 - здесь написано в каких. Также в манифесте вместо meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"  используйте android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно сообщению ТС в [комменте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455499/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-mapfragment-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-viewpager-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0#comment491094_455499) проблема была в отсутствии SHA-1 дебажного ключа, коим было подписано приложение