# Не грузит fragment c GoogleMap по релизу

Tags: android

По примеру старт андроида добавил `Activity` с картой, поставил метки, запустил на устройстве через шнурок, и все отлично. Но вот после того как залил его в маркет, видны иконки виджета, но самой карты и меток на ней нет.
Я создал в консоли проект, добавил название пакета и SHA-1, который сгенерировал в консоли , получил API key, который перенес в проект - в манифест, но ничего не случилось...
Уже перерыл первые страницы гугла, пробовал вроде бы уже все варианты, может кто подскажет куда глянуть?)
Заранее спасибо!)

Manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

google_maps_key

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
</string>
```

L

```
<fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".WashingMap"/>
```

В gradle такое добавил, после чего тест заработал, но релиз нет

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            resValue 'string', 'google_maps_key', 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
        debug {
            resValue 'string', 'google_maps_key', 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Скорее всего вам надо указать два ключа в google-services фалйе - дебажный и релизный

Comment: Теперь и на подключенном устройстве тоже самое... Вообще не понятно куда копать(

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вставьте ваш Google Maps API key в файл который расположен

```
 ВашПроект\app\src\release\res\values\google_maps_api.xml
```

Ваш ключ по-видимому лежит только для debug'ной версии в

```
 ВашПроект\app\src\debug\res\values\google_maps_api.xml
```

А из gradle файла можете убрать что вы там написали

Comment: <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </string>
Вот так у меня

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно. Там есть два таких файла. Один  в папке release, другой в папке debug. Недавно у меня самого была такая проблема. Ключ должен быть прописан в обоих файлах

Comment: Эх... расцеловал бы)))

Как только моя репутация перескочит за 15 поставлю плюсик!)

Comment: Только без поцелуев!!!