# андроид google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Почему после публикаций приложений в плэй маркет,google map не работает,если же компилирую через android studio все норм?

Comment: попробуйте этот ответ http://stackoverflow.com/a/18982638/5634351

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552467/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82-fragment-c-googlemap-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83/552606#552606

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего ключ у вас для debug версии приложения. 
Для release версии вам нужно на [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com) указать:
Название пакета, к примеру - com.example.pro
Контрольная сумма сертификата SHA-1.
Чтобы получить контрольную сумму, выполните следующую команду:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
```